# Sorting Kendo UI Jquery treeview child items in each parent item A-Z

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

Hey all I am trying to find the correct way to order/sort my child names in order from A-Z.

Currently my treeview looks like this:

[image]

And this is how I would like to sort it:

[image]

The data is coming in via JSON like so (using the above example):

```
[{
        "Name": "AU",
        "Description": null,
        "Id": "xxx",
        "DocumentType": null,
        "Category": "Academic",
        "Icon": null,
        "ProviderId": 2
    }, {
        "Name": "Gitlab",
        "Description": null,
        "Id": "xxx",
        "DocumentType": null,
        "Category": "Code Repos",
        "Icon": null,
        "ProviderId": 2
    }, {
        "Name": "B",
        "Description": null,
        "Id": "xxx",
        "DocumentType": null,
        "Category": "Dating",
        "Icon": null,
        "ProviderId": 2
    }, {
        "Name": "GitHubCommits",
        "Description": null,
        "Id": "xxx",
        "DocumentType": null,
        "Category": "Code Repos",
        "Icon": null,
        "ProviderId": 2
    }, {
        "Name": "GitHub",
        "Description": null,
        "Id": "xxx",
        "DocumentType": null,
        "Category": "Code Repos",
        "Icon": null,
        "ProviderId": 2
    }, {
        "Name": "Re",
        "Description": null,
        "Id": "xxx",
        "DocumentType": null,
        "Category": "Academic",
        "Icon": null,
        "ProviderId": 2
    }, {
        "Name": "Ir",
        "Description": null,
        "Id": "xxx",
        "DocumentType": null,
        "Category": "Dating",
        "Icon": null,
        "ProviderId": 2
    }, {
        "Name": "Ru",
        "Description": null,
        "Id": "xxx",
        "DocumentType": null,
        "Category": "Academic",
        "Icon": null,
        "ProviderId": 2
    }, {
        "Name": "LoveA",
        "Description": null,
        "Id": "xxx",
        "DocumentType": null,
        "Category": "Dating",
        "Icon": null,
        "ProviderId": 2
    }, {
        "Name": "LoveH",
        "Description": null,
        "Id": "xxx",
        "DocumentType": null,
        "Category": "Dating",
        "Icon": null,
        "ProviderId": 2
    },.........
]
```

Note that the JSON above does not come in any type of order and there are also other category's but I left those out for simplicity sake. The Category names themselves are in order by me doing this:

```
dataSource: {
   data: resultData,
   schema: {
       model: {
          children: 'items'
       },
       parse: (data) => {
          let newData = [];

           //Re-order catagory names A-Z
           data.sort((a, b) => (a.Category > b.Category) ? 1 : -1);

....
```

The rest of the above code looks like this::

```
           data.forEach(item => {
              let parent = newData.find(parentItem => parentItem.text === item.Category);

              if (!parent) {
                 //The beginning of the tree category
                 parent = {
                     id: 2,
                     text: item.Category,
                     expanded: true,
                     items: [],
                     imageUrl: "" + item.Icon + ""
                 };

                 newData.push(parent);
              }

              parent.items.push({
                 //Each "child" under the above category
                 id: 3,
                 text: item.Name,
                 imageUrl: "" + item.Icon + ""
              });
           });

           return [{
              id: 1,
              text: 'Categories',
              expanded: true,
              items: newData
           }];
       }
   }
 }
});
```

How would I, using the code above, sort also the child items under each category name?

I've tried already adding this to the code:

```
sort: {
   field: "Name", 
   dir: "asc"
}
```

But that does not seem to do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
newData.forEach(item => {
    if (item.items || item.items.length) {
        item.items.sort((a, b) => (a.text > b.text) ? 1 : -1);
    }
});
```

... before the `return` in `parse` event.

Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/local-data-binding">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.511/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.511/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.511/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    

</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">

    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <div>
            <div id="treeview-left"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var inlineDefault = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            data: [{
                "Name": "AU",
                "Description": null,
                "Id": "xxx",
                "DocumentType": null,
                "Category": "Academic",
                "Icon": null,
                "ProviderId": 2
            }, {
                "Name": "Gitlab",
                "Description": null,
                "Id": "xxx",
                "DocumentType": null,
                "Category": "Code Repos",
                "Icon": null,
                "ProviderId": 2
            }, {
                "Name": "B",
                "Description": null,
                "Id": "xxx",
                "DocumentType": null,
                "Category": "Dating",
                "Icon": null,
                "ProviderId": 2
            }, {
                "Name": "GitHubCommits",
                "Description": null,
                "Id": "xxx",
                "DocumentType": null,
                "Category": "Code Repos",
                "Icon": null,
                "ProviderId": 2
            }, {
                "Name": "GitHub",
                "Description": null,
                "Id": "xxx",
                "DocumentType": null,
                "Category": "Code Repos",
                "Icon": null,
                "ProviderId": 2
            }, {
                "Name": "Re",
                "Description": null,
                "Id": "xxx",
                "DocumentType": null,
                "Category": "Academic",
                "Icon": null,
                "ProviderId": 2
            }, {
                "Name": "Ir",
                "Description": null,
                "Id": "xxx",
                "DocumentType": null,
                "Category": "Dating",
                "Icon": null,
                "ProviderId": 2
            }, {
                "Name": "Ru",
                "Description": null,
                "Id": "xxx",
                "DocumentType": null,
                "Category": "Academic",
                "Icon": null,
                "ProviderId": 2
            }, {
                "Name": "LoveA",
                "Description": null,
                "Id": "xxx",
                "DocumentType": null,
                "Category": "Dating",
                "Icon": null,
                "ProviderId": 2
            }, {
                "Name": "LoveH",
                "Description": null,
                "Id": "xxx",
                "DocumentType": null,
                "Category": "Dating",
                "Icon": null,
                "ProviderId": 2
            }],
          schema: {
           model: {
              children: 'items'
           },
           parse: (data) => {
              let newData = [];

               //Re-order catagory names A-Z
               data.sort((a, b) => (a.Category > b.Category) ? 1 : -1);
             
               data.forEach(item => {
                let parent = newData.find(parentItem => parentItem.text === item.Category);

                if (!parent) {
                   //The beginning of the tree category
                   parent = {
                       id: 2,
                       text: item.Category,
                       expanded: true,
                       items: [],
                       imageUrl: "" + item.Icon + ""
                   };

                   newData.push(parent);
                }

                parent.items.push({
                   //Each "child" under the above category
                   id: 3,
                   text: item.Name,
                   imageUrl: "" + item.Icon + ""
                });
             });
             
             newData.forEach(item => {
               if (item.items || item.items.length) {
                item.items.sort((a, b) => (a.text > b.text) ? 1 : -1);
               }
             });

             return [{
                id: 1,
                text: 'Categories',
                expanded: true,
                items: newData
             }];
           }
         }
        });

        $("#treeview-left").kendoTreeView({
            dataSource: inlineDefault
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .demo-section{
            display:flex;
            justify-content:space-evenly;
        }
    </style>
</div>


    

</body>
</html>
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/UTOqAYaX)

Note that *GitHubCommits* will never come on top of *GitHub* in a common text sorting. Also note that the code i suggested only works for one level of items, for more levels it will need to be recursive.

Comment: Awesome job there DontVoteMeDown - that worked just fine. I also like the user name :)

Comment: @StealthRT nice that it didn't needed too much code to work. thanks, and thanks for not voting me down haha